# How can I store the number one trillion in Java?

Tags: java, primitive

I am attempting to store the number one trillion in a variable. However eclipse continues to worn that it is out of its range even when the variable type is a long.

Here is my code:

```
long temp = 1;

if(...){
    temp = 1000000000000;
}
```

If anyone has any insight into why this is occurring, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Add a [`L`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) or use [`BigInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

try

```
temp = 1000000000000L;
```

java in 1000000000000 is recognized as int, add L to the end to make it long

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm fairly new to programming and I never came across that.

Comment: @rmp2150 - this is why it is recommended that people who are a new to a language do the tutorial and/or buy and read a textbook.  This will be in the section of the tutorial or book that covers literals.

Answer (score 0):

Java has a BigInteger type in the math library.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html

Example:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
public class BigIntegerExample 
{
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
  BigInteger bigInteger1 = new BigInteger ("123456789");
  BigInteger bigInteger2 = new BigInteger ("112334");
  BigInteger bigIntResult =
    bigInteger1.multiply(bigInteger2); 
  System.out.println("Result is  ==> " + bigIntResult);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An `int` in Java is a signed 32bit, so the largest int value is 2,147,483,647. Using a long to represent a larger number like 1 trillion is a good option.

```
long temp = 1000000000000L;
```

To learn more about Java's primitive data types and *their limitations*, I would highly recommend referring to this Oracle article on [Primitive Data Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html).